# How to deploy a simple java app using heroku?

Tags: java, heroku

I am trying to deploy a simple hello app to heroku to learn about it.
Code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

I tried deploying the app using heroku. I created the jar, added the plugin in the pom.xml file, and created the procfile. I manage to upload the app to heroku but when I open the app with heroku open I get an error.
This is what I always get in the heroku logs --tail:

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=salty-ridge-42651.herokuapp.com request_id=d7ba0db5-e33c-47be-b4b8-409eb7
dcdc19 fwd="89.137.59.237" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: I followed the exact same steps as here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java#build-your-app-and-run-it-locally

Comment: "Whenever your app experiences an error, Heroku will return a standard error page with the HTTP status code 503. To help you debug the underlying error, however, the platform will also add custom error information to your logs. Each type of error gets its own error code, with all HTTP errors starting with the letter H and all runtime errors starting with R. Logging errors start with L." (see: [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes) )